# PUSH notifications in Outsystems with Onesignal

Tags: android, onesignal, outsystems

I've a lot of questions about PUSH notifications in Outsystems with Onesignal plugin:

1. How to add Onesignal plugin to Outsystems?
2. How do I connect Token or API to the app? (For ex, this is an Android application in the outsystems environment)
3. If i've Onesignal plugin and he's enabled, how to add PUSH-notification to button in action? (For ex, When you click on the button after the main actions, the user gets a test notification)

I hope you will help me :)

I tried everything, there is no clear documentation

Comment: I can temporarily understand what you mean that you want to be able to receive notifications even when the application is turned off. Imagine it like this. When your application runs, you must simultaneously run a parallel service in the background, and when you close the application, the service must still be active to receive notifications from OneSignal. When you receive a signal from Onesignal, you will push your notification

Comment: Here is the related document and to do it search with the keyword background and notifications in android. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using pubnub try to look on this url, (https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/api-reference/publish-and-subscribe#receive-messages)